# How to get excel to return NA for missing rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a code that looks for `_con_` in the row above a row containing the string `Response`, or in the row above that one. However, sometimes it happens that participants fail to respond. Hence, there will be no `Response` in the row below the row containing `_con_`. In such cases I would like to get N/A returned

My code works like this. There is a column with the following formula, that finds if there is a `_con_` in the rows `D16` or `D17` (in this example) above the row that contains `Response` (18 in this example)

```
=IF(AND(C18="Response";OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_con_";D16));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_con_";D17))));MAX(N$5:N17)+1;"-")
```

In another column I have a code that then finds the value in `column F` that corresponds to the row containing `Response`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F;MATCH(ROWS($1:1);N:N;0));"")
```

How can I change this code such that is knows when `_con_` appears while there is no `Response` in the row below (or two rows below)? As a result continue counting in the cell with the first line of code `(IF(AND...)`.

In addition, there are two things I need from the second line of code `(=IFERROR...` in the case of no Response: 1) Return NA in one column, 2) Return the value from column E in the same row as *con*. Basically I would need two different codes for that in separate columns.

I have tried flipping around the formula to look for Response instead, but it is not working:
    =IF(AND(D17="*con*";OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Response";C18));ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Response";C19))));MAX(N$5:N17)+1;"-")

Here is an example, the green row where I do have a Response, the red row where I don't get a Response.

[image]

And here is a picture of the column that uses the counter in column N to link it with the value in column F in the Response row. If there is no Response, this one needs to contain NA. I will make an additional column for the values in column E (not shown here).

I hope this makes it more clear.

[image]

This is my intended outcome:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be super helpful if you can elaborate. For example, in which cell exactly is the first formula (`=IF(AND...`)? What is the formula in Column F? The second formula (`=IFERROR(INDEX...`) uses Column N, what is in there? Can you can provide a small part of the data?

Comment: Thanks, I have included some pictures now. Column N contains a counter. If there is a response, 1 will be added up, this counter is used by another column in order to retrieve the corresponding values from column F in that specific row. I hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. Below are the data and results I have:

[image: Data and Results].

As you see, I use columns to not complicate the formulas.

- Column U checks whether Column D in the same row has `_con_` inside. Hence, the formula for U6 would be `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_con_";D6));1;0)`. I convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` into `1`/`0` for reasons that will become apparent.
- Column V checks whether Column C in row one below is `Response`. Hence, the formula for V6 would be `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Response";C7));1;0)`. Notice the conversion to number, this number will be the offset to be added to the index of `_con_`.
- Column W is similar to V, checks two below. The formula for W6: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Response";C8));2;0)`
- We merge V and W in Column X. Formula for X6: `=IF(AND(U6;SUM(V6:W6)>0);SUM(V6:W6);NA())`
- Column Y holds the count of `_con_`s. It is nonzero for rows where Column D has `_con_`, 0 elsewhere. Formula for Y6: `=IF(U6=1;SUM($U$2:U6);0)`. Here is the reason for conversion in Column U.
- Column AA is the list you want. The formula is similar to yours, but there is the addition of the value in Column X to the index of `_con_`. The formula for AA6: `=IFERROR(INDEX($F:$F; MATCH(ROWS($1:5);Y:Y;0) + INDEX(X:X; MATCH(ROWS($1:5);Y:Y;0) ) );NA())`

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, it works perfectly! :D I only changed ROWS to $1:1 in the last formula to make it loop through my entire sheet.

Comment: I am glad I could help.